# Java primitive type bit size on Android

Tags: java, android

In a Java program running on the JVM, primitive data types have guaranteed bit size. e.g.

```
byte      8-bit
short    16-bit
int      32-bit
```

et cetera.

Are these bit sizes guaranteed on Android as well? I've been looking for documentation on Android Developers for confirmation. Any links to documentation are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are these bit sizes guaranteed on Android as well?

Yes they are.  Otherwise, Java libraries would not be portable to Android.

---

And the documentation says so ...

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

which says in the first sentence:

> Android applications are written in the Java programming language.

The Java programming language explicitly specifies the sizes and semantics of all primitive types.  If the sizes were different on an Android implementation, that implementation would be in fundamental violation of the (relevant) Java language specification ... and therefore NOT JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

You can confirm this by checking the wrapper classes, e.g., [java.lang.Byte](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Byte.html#SIZE) confirms that a Byte is 8 bits, [Character](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html#SIZE) is 16, and [Integer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#SIZE) is 32.